# connecting teradata from python without terada driver

Tags: python, teradata, connectivity

I'm trying to connect to Teradata without using Teradata driver. so installed the teradatasql package and written the below code to connect.

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd

with teradatasql.connect(host='abc.abc.net', user='abcabc', password='abce123') as connect;
    query = "select * from abc.emp;"
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
    print (df.head())
```

when executing the above code I'm getting the Invalid syntax error at the below line

```
with teradatasql.connect(host='abc.abc.net', user='abcabc', password='abce123') as connect;

                                                                                        ^
```

can you help me with the code to connect to teradata

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the a semicolon (;) with a colon (:)

The correct syntax for with is:

```
with expression [as variable]:
    with-block
```

In your case:

```
with teradatasql.connect(host='abc.abc.net', user='abcabc', password='abce123') as connect:
   query = ...
```